# Proof involving determinant and inverse of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $P$ $\in$ $\Bbb Z^{n,n}$, det$(P)$ $\neq$ $0$.

Prove: det$(P)$ $\in$ $\{$$-1, 1$$\}$ if and only if $P^{-1}$ $\in$ $\Bbb Z^{n,n}$.

Please can anyone help me out here?

Comment: $P^{-1}=(\det P)^{-1}\mathrm{adj}(P)$, where $\mathrm{adj}(P)$ is the adjugate matrix.

Comment: What are the only units in $\Bbb Z $?

Comment: For the "if" direction, note that determinants of integer-valued matrices are themselves integers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\det(P) \notin \{\pm 1\}$, then $\det(P^{-1}) = 1/\det(P) \notin \Bbb Z$.  So, $P^{-1}$ can't possibly be a matrix with integer entries.

On the other hand: if $\det(P) \in \{\pm 1\}$, then $P^{-1}$ is given by the formula
$$
P^{-1} = \frac{1}{\det(P)} \operatorname{adj}(P)
$$
Where adj denotes the [adjugate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix#Inverses).  Since $\operatorname{adj}(P)$ is a matrix with integer entries, so is $P^{-1}$.